# How to remove duplicate using union all

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Just reading this site https://www.toptal.com/sql/interview-questions

they show this trick to remove duplicate using union all

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE a = X 

UNION ALL 

SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE b = Y AND a != X
```

The above script is not clear to me. Suppose I want to fetch data from two employee table but like to remove duplicate using union all with where clause.

Suppose my employee table has structure like ID, Name and salary.

Now post a sample SQL using `union all` which will show distinct rows from 2 tables.

Comment: That interview Q and A you link as it stands is just nonsense. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMRjX.png If there was some background information that you were supposed to be starting off with a query like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE a = X UNION ALL SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE b = Y` then maybe it would make sense but this doesn't appear to be present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IF and ONLY IF** you have to use a UNION ALL otherwise I would go with Handoko Chen's solution

```
Select Distinct *
 From (
        Select * From Employee1
        Union All
        Select * From Employee2
      ) A
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's UNION that removes duplicates. Let's say I have 3 rows of data in a table. Then use 2 unioned queries. See the differences between union and union all.

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Salary  INT
)

INSERT @Employee VALUES
(1, 'Alice', 50000),
(2, 'Bob', 40000),
(3, 'Charlie', 60000)

SELECT ID, Name, Salary FROM @Employee WHERE Salary >= 50000
UNION
SELECT ID, Name, Salary FROM @Employee WHERE Salary >= 60000

SELECT ID, Name, Salary FROM @Employee WHERE Salary >= 50000
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, Salary FROM @Employee WHERE Salary >= 60000
```

Result:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| ID | Name    | Salary |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | Alice   | 50000  |
| 3  | Charlie | 60000  |
+----+---------+--------+

+----+---------+--------+
| ID | Name    | Salary |
+----+---------+--------+
| 1  | Alice   | 50000  |
| 3  | Charlie | 60000  |
| 3  | Charlie | 60000  |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Comment: so u mean to say with union all duplicate can't be removed....am i right?

Comment: Plus+  Good illustration

Comment: any tool is used to create output or is it hand crafted?

Comment: @Mou See this [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables). The one I used was [this](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/).

Answer (score 2):

```
create table test_a(id numeric);

create table test_b(id numeric);

insert into test_a(id) values
  (10),
  (20),
  (30),
  (40),
  (50);

insert into test_b(id) values
  (10),
  (30),
  (50);
 GO 
 select * from test_b
 union all
  SELECT * FROM(select * from test_a  
  except 
  select * from test_b) ABC
```

Comment: Please add some commentary to your answer

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` removes duplicates. And why not use it between my table and 'nothing' with the same structure of course.

Here is the sentence:

```
select id, name from mytable 

  UNION

  select id, name from mytable 
  where 1=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  from table1 where ID not in(select ID from table1) union all select  from table1;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**